# Is it possible to make a pop up message without clicking on any button?

Tags: android, popup, message

```
   AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    myAlert.setMessage(username)
            .setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setTitle("Welcome To iShop!")
            .create();
    myAlert.show();
```

It is possible to make it just popup when the activity starts?

Comment: Well, I think your code should work as is.

Comment: Yes you can create any Dialog to show when the activity is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the code you wrote inside the the Activity's onCreate() method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    myAlert.setMessage(username)
        .setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        })
        .setTitle("Welcome To iShop!")
        .create();
    myAlert.show();
}
```